# Corrupted Installation of Discord on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I have installed Discord on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I run it via terminal:

> discord

And it's working fine, but on the top of the screen it says my installation is corrupted and I should fix it. There's also a *"Help!"* button which upon click, just opens a new empty web browser window.

Anyone know how I can fix my installation? I have tried reinstalling it and it's still the same.

Answer (score 8):

To fix this "issue" make sure that you have all dependencies installed, especially libatomic1.

```
'libc6',
'libasound2',
'libatomic1',
'libgconf-2-4',
'libnotify4',
'libnspr4',
'libnss3',
'libstdc++6',
'libxss1',
'libxtst6',
'libappindicator1',
'libc++1',
```

Try installing the *libatomic1* library, worked for me:

```
sudo apt install libatomic1
```

<sub>I personally used `sudo dnf install libatomic`, but on Fedora. [Source (reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/7euehr/need_some_help_with_my_installation_on_linux/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks!
`    sudo apt-get update`
`    sudo apt-get install libatomic-ops-dev`

Is this how you install that library?

Comment: Well personally, I did as mentioned in my answer `sudo dnf install libatomic` but I'm using Fedora so I suppose `sudo apt-get install libatomic` should do the job for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the same problem on Centos 7 and resolved it with the corresponding `sudo yum install libatomic` and all was good after that.

Comment: Fixed Discord for me on Void Linux. `sudo xbps-install -S libatomic`

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the Discord config folder worked for me:

```
rm -r ~/.config/discord
```

If you're afraid to delete the folder you can just rename the original folder:

```
mv ~/.config/discord ~/.config/discord_backup
```

Then close any open discord instances and open it again.

It will log you out, but it will go back to normal after you log in.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 I've tried everything: purging the installation, deleting the config dir, installing the dependencies mentioned in other posts, using the `*.tar.gz` version, but the only thing that got rid of the error message was to uninstall everything and install the SNAP version.

I removed the old installation and configuration:

```
pkill Discord
rm -r $HOME/.config/discord
apt-get purge discord
```

installed the SNAP version:

```
snap install discord
```

started Discord from the KDE launcher and logged in, and the red banner was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This worked for me in Elementary OS, as it check and install dependencies for the corrupt package.
It works with all those `sudo dpkg -i packageName` as dpkg doesn't install any dependencies, but it keeps registry that `apt` can get and fix.